# PHP Getting first value out of array, then skipping the second

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

How would I get the first value out of an array, and then skipping the second

Cause I only want the first values, cause the second one is a duplicate

[See image for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOQEp.jpg)

Maybe it would help if I were to include some code of what I'm trying to achieve

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT gameBanner, gameNaam, gameOmschrijvingBrief, gameJaar, gameNr FROM game WHERE gameActief = 1");
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        if(count($result)){
            foreach ($result as $value){
                if(is_array($value)){
                    foreach($value as $values){
        ?>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="imgBox">
                <img src="images/stock-images/<?php echo$values ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="content">
                    <h2><?php echo$values ?><br><span>
                    <?php echo$values ?></span>
                    </h2>
                    <a href="game_id=<?php echo$values ?>">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "Er zijn (nog) geen games geregistreerd uit dat jaar.";
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: change `$result = $stmt->fetchAll();`  to `$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: ``DISTINCT`` cmd can be used to get all non-repeating values. You can also call the ``array_unique()`` method on the resultant array to remove any duplicate values.

Comment: it's because you are fetching both associative and index data using `fetchAll()` . Use `fetchAll(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` or `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` to get associative array only.

Comment: @WM-SH-PD-TV-FC Thanks, that worked perfectly, the issue that I'm getting right now, is that I don't want it loop 10 times, I only want it to loop once and go to the next set of data. I tried a while "loop", but that didn't work (Or maybe I didn't do it propperly). But do you have a suggestion for that problem as well?

Comment: @MauritsVanBeek  unable to understand you now